# Setting focus on flash content instantly after load

Tags: javascript, flash, browser

I searched through internet and found a lot of threads and solutions concerning this problem, but no one works for me. Tried almost everything including swfobject, javascript focus, custom writed functions inside swfobject and so. Tried focus after DOM load and got the same results. I just wanted my keyboard keys to work just after someone open the link.

My browser is Firefox26 but it is the same in all browsers. Why is this so hard to make? If anyone had a working solution I will be extremely grateful! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've used this successfully.  In the Application, register a creationComplete handler:

```
<s:Application .....  creationComplete="doInit()" ....>

protected function doInit():void {
    // Force the browser to give forus to the app
    ExternalInterface.call('function() {
                                var app = document.getElementById("<your app name>");
                                app.focus();
                            }');
}
```